# What is bltoolkit's BLTgen tool and how it should be used?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, orm, bltoolkit

I guess it is something like sgen.exe which generates some serialization classes in separate assembly. Is that it? Should generated assembly be referenced? If so, by which project?

I have noticed that some LINQ queries are very slow, when executed for first time. Maybe bltgen tool can help?

I'll start a bltoolkit blog when I find all this answers :)

@Admin: Please add bltoolkit tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLTGen emits type accessors and abstract classes. In the following example you can find how to configure your project to use BLTGen - http://www.bltoolkit.net/Doc.PartialTrust.ashx.

Generated assemblies do not have to be signed.

BLTGen may speed up LINQ queries a little bit, however I think the problem is loading and initializing .NET framework components for first time use.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. First time slowness seems to be an issue specific to BLToolkit (confirmed by stepping trough the source). In some scenarios it will take a LOT of time (seconds) to generate a query for the first time. We were unable to find any way to get around this.